# What is the convention for "large" families of sets?

Tags: soft-question, set-theory, terminology, convention

**Premises:**

**definition** (class): A primitive object. Left undefined.

**definition** (proper class and set): A class is *proper* iff it is not a member of another class. A class which is a member of another class is called a *set*.

**definition** (family of sets): A class $\mathscr F$ is a *family of sets* on a class $C$ iff $\bigcup \mathscr F=C$. (typically, this would be called a "cover," but every family of sets is a cover of its union anyway, so the distinction is largely irrelevant; and "family" just sounds better than "cover".)

We call a family $\mathscr F$ a *Russell family*$^1$ iff $\bigcup \mathscr F\in\mathscr F$. Many important families of sets are Russell families. For exmple, all of the following are Russell families

- Powersets
- Topologies
- Filters
- Join-complete lattices and semilattices
- $\lambda$-systems and $\sigma$-algebras

---

**Problem:**

No large family of sets (a family of sets over a proper class) can be a Russell family. The proof is straightforward:

Suppose towards contradiction that $\mathscr F$ is a Russell family on a proper class $C$. Since $C$ is a proper class, $C\notin X$ for any class $X$. In particular, $C\notin\mathscr F$. But $\mathscr F$ is a Russel family, so $C=\bigcup\mathscr F\in\mathscr F$ - a contradiction.

Unfortunately, there are times when we would like to talk about conventionally Russell families on *proper classes*. The obvious example for me is the order topology on the class of ordinals. By the previous, there can't really be *any* topology on the class of ordinals - or any other proper class, for that matter. Similarly, we cannot rightly discuss ultrafilters on proper classes, or the lattice of sets formed by inclusion on a proper class, because all of these structures are Russell families.

This does not stop set theorists from doing so anyway.

Now I can see a few different ways to clean things up: we can avoid talking about large families altogether and focus on the properties of arbitrary families on subsets of proper classes instead. e.g. "fix an ordinal $\gamma$..."; we can redefine various structures so that they are only Russell families when the domain is a set, or so that they don't need to be Russell families in the first place; we can introduce a heirarchy of "logical types" a la Principia Mathematica - with sets as 1-types, classes of sets which are not themeselves sets as 2-types, collections of classes as 3-types, and so on; or we can don robes and chant "higher category theory" until all the boomers leave the room.

Whatever the case, is there a widely accepted convention for handling large families of sets?

$^1$ this is just a placeholder name; feel free to change it if there's already canonical name for this property.

Comment: For a foundationally sensitive matter like this, there really can't be a uniform convention. Problems about a large Russell family will depend on what theory you're working in. For the case of the order topology on Ord, notice that for any property $\varphi,$ the assertion "$\{\alpha: \varphi(\alpha)\}$ is open" is expressible in first order set theory, so in this case it makes sense to discuss topological problems about Ord in ZFC unless it is necessary to quantify over open classes, in which case it would probably make more sense to reason in NBG or MK.

Comment: @ElliotGlazer Even working in NBG, an open class is made "open" by virtue of being a member of a topology. A proper class can't be a member of a topology, or it wouldn't be proper (in particular, Ord cannot belong to the topology on Ord.) This is the part that I figure is a matter of convention. There must be some kind of gimmick that makes it acceptable to talk about large Russell families in the first place - some workaround that let's us say "..., then $\mathscr F$ is a [structure] on $C$" without implying "[proper class] is a member of $\mathscr F$."

Comment: In NBG, there is a definition $\varphi$ (which only use set quantifiers) such that for any class $C,$ $C$ is open iff $\varphi(C).$ So the order topology on Ord is a definable hyperclass. I don't think this is any more problematic than $V$ not being a formal object in first-order set theory.

Comment: Speaking of Russell, he and Whitehead put together a set theory that did not stop at just "sets" and "classes". Instead it has an entire hierarchy of classes. First order classes are sets, 2nd order classes are proper classes, 3rd order classes have first and second order as members, etc. The logic R & W came up with is torturous, so few people are familiar with the actual theory, but the work itself (Principia Mathematica) is famous.